# where to set header for access control origin in apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, drupal, drupal-7

Have added/set the header for access control in .htaccess file of the directory where the web application is present (drupal) . but when making a ajax request for it with jquery, the console error gives following message:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost/drupal/get/news. 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:56687' is therefore not allowed access.
```

the .htaccess is insider the folder "drupal" and the header is set at the following:

```
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>

   Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"

    # Serve gzip compressed CSS files if they exist and the client accepts gzip.
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-encoding} gzip
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.gz -s
    RewriteRule ^(.*)\.css $1\.css\.gz [QSA]

    # Serve gzip compressed JS files if they exist and the client accepts gzip.
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-encoding} gzip
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.gz -s
    RewriteRule ^(.*)\.js $1\.js\.gz [QSA]

    # Serve correct content types, and prevent mod_deflate double gzip.
    RewriteRule \.css\.gz$ - [T=text/css,E=no-gzip:1]
    RewriteRule \.js\.gz$ - [T=text/javascript,E=no-gzip:1]

    <FilesMatch "(\.js\.gz|\.css\.gz)$">
      # Serve correct encoding type.
      Header set Content-Encoding gzip
      # Force proxies to cache gzipped & non-gzipped css/js files separately.
      Header append Vary Accept-Encoding
    </FilesMatch>
  </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header there when you visit the page normally? If not, is mod_headers enabled in Apache?

Comment: thank you for the comment. am not very good with server configurations.have added the header after some searches but it doesnt seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost/drupal/get/news.
```

The above means that in your Drupal CMS, **you have references pointing to your localhost**. My guess is that you constructed your site locally, and then migrated to a live server, but in doing so, some of the references are not yet changed. I would recommend you to replace all `http://localhost` instances in your **.sql** file with `http://yourdomain.com` since the files are meant to be publicly available and no one else can access your localhost resources from outside network.